# Cannot read X Y dimension from OCO-2 Satellite Dataset NetCDF4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf

I have downloaded some data from the OCO-2 satellite and what to show it spatially in ArcGIS (10.5). I have done this with the AIRS and AQUA satellites of the same file types and there is not issue. The file extension is ".nc" and the file type that I downloaded was "NetCDF 4".

Below is screenshot of the "NetCDF to Feature Class" tool. When I select the variable that I want, there is nothing to select in the lat and long fields. 
The lat and long variables are available in the "Variables" drop down, but not in the X and Y.

[image]

This guy is having the same problem as me, but his question is unanswered:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/168798

Here is where I downloaded the file from:
https://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/granlist.pl?page=1&dataSet=OCO2_L2_Standard&version=7&allversion=7&version=7r&allversion=7r&keyword=OCO&pointLocation=(-90,-180),(90,180)&location=(-90,-180),(90,180)&searchType=Location&event=&startTime=2009-03-31&endTime=2017-01-27%2023:59:59&search=&CGISESSID=7869eb21869b19ce4393bb1280781991&nr=21361&temporalres=16%20days&prodpg=http://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datacollection/OCO2_L2_Standard_V7r.html&longname=OCO-2%20Level%202%20geolocated%20XCO2%20retrievals%20results,%20physical%20model,%20Retrospective%20Processing%20V7r&granulePresentation=ungrouped